# Do any universities, other than Pontifical (Vatican) universities allows for presenting a thesis in Latin?

Tags: thesis, latin

What, if any, universities, permit candidates to put forth their thesis in Latin (classical or ecclesiastical)?

For this question, I would like to exclude any [Pontifical Universities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontifical_university).

In other words, I would like to know if any other universities allow a candidate to put forth their thesis in the Latin language, at the present moment in time.

Comment: _De adverbiis pronominalibus localibus latinis: Studia semantica et syntactica_
by Palmen, Erkki, D.Phil., Jyvaskylan Yliopisto (Finland), 1998, 286 pages

Comment: If memory serves, Cambridge allows PhDs to be submitted in Latin, but no one actually does. Not putting it as an answer because this is half remembered in my years since being a PhD student there.